# Trying to identify a fairly old (fifty -sixty years) star ship novel

Tags: story-identification

In this novel humans live in an almost jungle like sealed in environment providing for their needs. A few of the inhabitants begin to question where they are and begin to more carefully explore. Eventually a control deck is discovered and they realize where they are at nearly the exact time of the arrival of the star ship at it's destination. If I remember correctly as the ship enters orbit around a planet, it begins to separate into segments in preparation for some sort of transfer to the planet's surface and the story ends there. There were no references to marital status that I remember tho that should not rule it out. I also remember a possible mention of the size of the surviving travelers having deminished over time tho given how much sci fi I read over the years that fact could be bleeding across from another story but maybe not.

Comment: This is a pretty common trope; **Orphans Of The Sky** by Robert A. Heinlein, **Non-Stop** by Brian W. Aldiss, **Captive Universe**
by Harry Harrison, **Songs of Distant Earth** by Arthur C Clarke and **The Star Seekers** by Milton Lesser all fit the description you've given.

Comment: Hey Valorum Brian Aldiss fits into my memory of this the best. I 'm just not sure about Non Stop quite yet.

Comment: To follow up on Valorum's comment, can you remember anything about the characters?  Names, actions, marital status, legends, etc.  Human and / or Mutant?  Societies (mystic 'scientists', 'officers', etc)?  The base idea has been seen a lot (there's even a related [Star Trek TOS episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_the_World_Is_Hollow_and_I_Have_Touched_the_Sky)); it's the details that will identify the specific story.

Comment: Be VERY careful following this link -- it takes you to TvTropes, and you can lose hours there without noticing.. but they have an article on [Generational Ships](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GenerationShips), and lists of related works, which might have what you are looking for.

Comment: I just edited the body Valorum to reflect your comment

Comment: Eric. I believe the Aldiss story is also called Star Ship. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Mike yes absolutely I was waiting for that. That's why I said earlier that Non Stop wasn't 't working for me. I'm wondering if it would be worth a question. Why two different names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost Certainly Brian W Aldiss' *Non Stop*. That ends with the ship breaking up into its component decks.

Comment: The jungle inside the ship is also a giveaway.

Comment: @Buzz - Really? All of the stories above have an un-tended jungle in them